# Is there a lodash method for merging one object into a mapped object?

Tags: javascript, redux, lodash

In my react/redux app I have an array of objects that come in from an API response that I convert into a mapped object via `_.mapyKeys` based on an object's `id`:

```
{
  1: {
    ...
  },
  2: {
    ...
  },
  3: {
    ..
  },
}
```

I now have an action where I create an object and want to insert it into my mapped object. I know how to do this using ES6:

```
data: {
  ...state.data,
  [action.payload.id]: { ...action.payload },
}
```

Just out of curiosity I was wondering if there was a way to do this using lodash. I know the opposite of inserting is `_.omit`.

Comment: I believe you’re looking for [`_.assign`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.14#assign), like in `_.assign(data, { [action.payload.id]: action.payload })`.

Comment: Wow. Thinking that if I used lodash it would shorten up my code but ended up looking almost the same if were to do this the ES6 way. Feel free to post this as an answer if you want and thank you!